# VUE no cargan las variables desde AsyncData

Tags: vue.js

tengo una pagina en NUXT donde se publican noticias, para cada post quiero tener los METAS de Title y Description personalizados.

Esto ya lo hago con el head()

```
 head() {
    return {
        title: this.title,
        meta: [
        {
            hid: 'description',
            name: 'description',
            content: this.yoast 
        }
    }
}
```

El problema es que las variables **this.title** y **this.yoast** se cargan más tarde, desde un asyncData,  que el Head, por lo que siempre se quedan los Metas en blanco.

¿Como puedo hacer que el Head no cargue hasta que estas dos variables tengan contenido?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Lo he conseguido, faltaba llamar en el head() las variables con el this.

```
head() {
    var title = ""
    var desc = ""
    var slug = this.$route.params.id
    
    title = this.title; 
    desc = this.text;

    return {
        title: title,
        meta: [
        {
            hid: 'description',
            name: 'description',
            content: desc
        },
```